Maximum number of vectors with pairwise non-positive inner product
Problem Statement: Consider $m$ distinct non-zero vectors $\boldsymbol{v}_1,\boldsymbol{v}_2,\ldots,\boldsymbol{v}_m\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfying:
$$
\forall i\neq j, \boldsymbol{v}_i \cdot \boldsymbol{v}_j \leq 0.
$$
Prove that $m\leq 2n$.
Motivation: This is a problem I encountered while studying coding theory. If the inner product $\boldsymbol{v}_i\cdot \boldsymbol{v}_j$ is strictly less than $0$, then $m \leq n + 1$,  which can be proven by contradiction. Since for $n+2$ n-dimensional vectors, the size of the largest independent set must be less than or equal to $n$, it ensures that among the non-zero coefficients $a_i$ that satisfy $\sum a_i\boldsymbol{v}_i=\boldsymbol{0}$, there are both positive and negative values. Refer here for details.
Ideas: I find the method mentioned above no more works because contradiction doesn't cover the situation where inner product equal to $0$. I know that "$=$" is achieved when $n$ vectors are orthogonal and the other $n$ vectors are in exactly the opposite direction. This inequality can be understood geometrically: each time a vector is chosen, the space is divided into two parts by a hyperplane perpendicular to that vector, with one side containing no other vectors. The process continues recursively. However, I am unsure how to prove this rigorously.

Hi and welcome to the site! It is advisable that you take a tour to see what we are about. Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "avoiding no-clue questions").

Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Could you try a bit by yourself, e.g. beginning in low dimension to see the mechanic

thanks for 5sum and julio_es_sui_glace's advice, I have added more details and my thoughts about this problem. :)

Let us prove this by induction. For $n=1$ this is clear. Now assume that this is true for some $n$. Let $S$ be our set of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that satisfy the condition. Note that we can always assume that the vectors are unit vectors, and also that $v_1=e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)\in S$ (by applying a unitary $U$ that sends $v_1$ to $e_1$, and considering $S'=\{Uv_1,\ldots, Uv_m\}$. This obviously doesn't change the condition).
Now note that for every $e_1\neq v\in S$, the first entry of $v$ cannot be positive. Define two sets:
$$A=\{v\in S:\text{$v$'s first entry is negative}\}$$
$$B=\{v\in S:\text{$v$'s first entry is $0$}\}$$
So $S=A\cup B\cup\{e_1\}$. Now we think of each $v_i\in A\cup B$ as $v_i=(x,u_i)$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If $v_i=(x_i,u_i),\,v_j=(x_j,u_j)\in A$, then $u_i\neq u_j$. Why? because if $u_i=u_j$ then $\langle v_i,v_j\rangle =  x_ix_j+\|u_i\|^2>0$, contradiction. This also shows that $\langle u_i, u_j\rangle\leq 0$. Same reasoning shows that if $v_i\neq v_j\in B$ then $u_i\neq u_j$ and $\langle u_i,u_j\rangle\leq 0$. Similarly for if $v_i\in A$ and $v_j\in B$.
Last thing to note is that at most one vector in $B$ is of the form $(x,0)$. Therefore we found a set $S'=\{u_2,\ldots,u_{k}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$
where $|S'|\in \{m-2,m-1\}$ (depending whether $B$ contains a vector of the form $(x,0)$),
that satisfies the same condition (non-zero and have pairwise non-positive inner product). By induction hypothesis:
$$|S'|\leq 2n$$
Therefore:
$$m-2\leq 2n\Rightarrow m\leq 2(n+1)$$
$$m-1\leq 2n\Rightarrow m\leq 2n+1\leq 2(n+1)$$

I have carefully read your proof, and it is correct. However, in the first sentence of the third paragraph, you mistakenly wrote $B$ instead of $A$, which should be "$A$ is of the form $(x,0)$". Thank you very much.

I think your statement is a little weird. If $m=2n$, I know you tend to construct the sequence $\{e_1,-e_1,e_2,-e_2......e_n,-e_n\}$. However, in this case, $e_i$ and $-e_i$ are on the same line. If you admit it, then $\{e_1,2e_1,3e_1......\}$ is actually an correct infinite sequence with $m=\infty$. We need to make sure that the vectors are not collinear. Actually, $m\leq n+1$.
If we have obtained $n+1$ vectors, as the dimension is $n$, so these exists not all zero $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{n+1}$, s.t. $\sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}\alpha_{i}v_{i}=0$, If there exists the $(n+2)^{th}$ vector $v_{n+2}$, then we calculate the inner product $\sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}\alpha_{i}v_{i}v_{n+2}=0v_{n+2}=0$. We know all $v_{i}v_{n+2}\leq 0$. W.L.O.G., we suppose $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{s}>0$, $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=s+1}^{t} <0$, $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=t+1}^{n+1}=0$.
Denote $V = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}\alpha_{i}v_{i} = -\sum_{i = s+1}^{t}\alpha_{i}v_{i}$. Here we use $\beta_i$ to replace the $-\alpha_i$ when $s+1\leq i\leq t$, so we have $V = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}\alpha_{i}v_{i} = \sum_{i = s+1}^{t}\beta_{i}v_{i}$ with $\alpha$ $\beta$ in this equation are all positive. Then $V^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}\sum_{j = s+1}^{t}\alpha_{i}\beta_{j}v_{i}v_{j} \leq 0$. It leads to $V^2 = 0$,and for all these $i,j$ $\,$ $v_{i}v_{j}=0$.(Here we use j to represent these i with $s+1\leq i \leq t$). However $\forall i', Vv_{i'} = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}\alpha_{i}v_{i}v_{i'} = \sum_{j = s+1}^{t}\beta_{j}v_{j}v_{i'} = 0$ so for all $i$, $v_{i}v_{i'}=0$, (similarly for $j'$). It means $\forall 1\leq m < n\leq t$, $\,$ $v_{m}v_{n} = 0$,  $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{t}$ are linearly independent. We reveal that $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=t+1}^{n+1}=0$, $\sum_{i = 1}^{n+1}\alpha_{i}v_{i}=\sum_{i = 1}^{t}\alpha_{i}v_{i}=0$, with $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^{t}$ are all non-zero. CONTRADICTION. So $v_{n+2}$ doesn't exist. $m_{max} = n+1$

I think there is some problem with your proof. We can suppose $\alpha_1$ to be $0$, but $t$ may not be greater than $s$, which means all $\alpha_i$ are either $0$ or positive. Actually, ${e_1,-e_1,\ldots, e_n, -e_n}$ is a valid solution because $-e_i\cdot e_i<0, e_ie_j=0,\forall i\neq j$.

Without loss of generality, I divided n+1 into three parts, 1~s  s+1~t  t+1~n+1, first s elements are positive, the middle t-s elements are negative, the last n-t elements are zeros. I think you might misunderstand this 't'.

I don't think the example is a valid solution, because $-e_1 = (-1)\times e_1$, if you allow it ,then you must allow $2\times e_1;3\times e_1......$, then you will have a sequence with infinite elements with $m=\infty$. Unless you add a condition : $\forall i, ||v_i||=1$

thanks for your reply. I think I did not misunderstand the meaning of "t". I know what you what to do, but how can you assume that exist two $a_i$ and $a_j$ with different sign? Let me give you an example, $v_1=1,v_2=-1$, you can only make $a_1$ and $a_2$ both positive or negative.

I can add $e_1$ and $-e_1$, but afterward, I can no longer add $ke_1$. There is no contradiction. You can also add $ke_1$ and $-ke_1$ and give up $e_1$.

Oh, I am sorry that I have made some typos in my comments. In the first comment, I wanted to say "We can suppose $\alpha_1$ to be positive".

I think it has no effect on the proof, $1\leq s\leq t\leq n+1$. Of course you can suppose $s=t=n+1$, so  there are only positive elements. We can still conclude that if $v_3$ exist, then $v_1,v_2$ are linear independent to get the contradiction.                ${v_1,-v_1,2v_1,-2v_1}$ is a sequence in $R^1$ which matches. but here $m=4>2*1$, if you don't  add a restriction, you can't prove $m<2n$, you can't give up $v_1,-v_1$ because we are searching for the maximum $m$

${1,-1}$ or ${2,-2}$ is valid in $\mathbb{R}$. However, ${1,-1,2,-2}$ is not, because $1\cdot 2=2>0$. If $t=s$, then you cannot conclude that $V=\boldsymbol{0}$ in your proof. Thanks again for your help. :)

If $t=s$, then $V = \sum_{i = 1}^{s}...=\sum_{s+1}^{t=s}...=0$, we can obtain V = 0 naturally.

I got it. It's true that $V=\boldsymbol{0}$, but you cannot conclude $v_mv_n=0$, because this time you can't apply $i'$ to $\sum_{j=s+1}^{t}\beta_jv_jv_{i'}$ and $j'$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{s}\alpha_iv_iv_{j'}$. If you apply $i'$ to the $\alpha$'s side, $v_{i'}v_{i'}>0$ then $v_mv_n=0$ is not true.

NONONO，Let's put it another way, we just named these positive$\alpha$ 'PART A', and these negative $\alpha$ 'PART B', $V^2 = PART A \times PART B$. Here $V=0$ concludes PART A orthogonalize with PART B(because the coefficients are positive, while any v_i v_j \leq 0, and ||V|| is not negative). Then consider PART A and PART B  respectively $PART A\times PART A=V\times PART A=0$ so the elements in PART A are orthogonal, $PART B\times PART B = V\times PART B=0$ so the elements in PART B  are orthogonal. Now we conclude PART A $\oplus$ PART B are orthogonal, which means linear independent.

I don't think $PART A\cdot PART A=0$ can infer that $\alpha_i(1\leq i\leq s)$ are linearly independent, instead, we can know $PART A=0$ which means they are linearly dependent. Here, I give you a counterexample to show that your conclusion is incorrect. Consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then ${(1, 0), (0,1),(-1,0), (0,-1)}$ is a solution.
